How to change stretch/centering of Lock Screen wallpaper on iOS 18?
My wallpaper album on my iPhone is showing most wallpapers off center on iOS 18 on my iPhone 15 Pro.
How do I change the fill/centering of my wallpapers in my album so they align nicely on my Lock Screen?
